# Vase mode extrusion calculation

Tags: extrusion, vase-mode

I am using Grasshopper for clay 3D printing and I have struggled with E calculus in vase mode especially when:

1. The layer **heights** are not equal (adaptive mode to ensure each layer touch below one)
2. Small layer height enough that a few point-to-point Z difference in layers do not surpass the 50-micron limit of the printer, for example, printer each 5 point will increase height once, and this leads to extrusion at that point

Please, how can this be done when I have:

- Distance between point to point
- Height difference between neighbor points
- Nozzle diameter